# Get all Mac-Adresses of an IP-Range (Powershell)

Tags: powershell

Is there a way to get all Mac Adresses of Devices in a specific IP-Range?

For Example: I want all the IP's and MAC form all devices in this Network 192.168.12.*

I have searched the Internet but couldent find any simple solution which worked for me.

THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: Depends on your network setup. [What](https://xyproblem.info/) are you trying to do with the hardware addresses anyway?

Comment: On the same subnet you can do get-netneighbor, which is like the old arp command.  Or export from your dhcp server.